# about browser cache, for optimize speed load website

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I'm trying to optimize the speed of my web app, and I'm controlling the load of the images at the moment.

I have an attribute named **webCache** and I use it for handle the **.src of each image object**...

```
if (!webCache) src += "?rand="+Math.random();
img.src =src;
```

If webCache if false, then I update the src var value adding a random value by using random()
And then, I add the new src value to the src attribute of object image.

My question is, if `webCache` is true, the conditional if isn't executed, and the `img.src =src;` is executed equally. The value is the same, src value hasn't changed, but the image can be another....How will behave the browser here? Will it refresh the image?

That is, if the src value is the same, but the image is another, how will behave the browser?

Comment: Press F12 in Google Chrome, the network tab shows all images that are being loaded and also if they were cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the http headers of the image when it was first served.

The server might have tolled the browser to always re-fetch the image, to not re-fetch the image for a certain period or until a specific point in time.

An ETag or Last-Modified header might also have been provided, allowing the browser to do a HEAD request to the server and inspect if should download the image or just use it's local copy.

Some relevant headers are

- Cache-Control
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- ETag

In google chrome you can disable caching for development purposes.
Press F12, click the wheel in the bottom right corner, select General and then check "Disable Caching"

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as solved if you feel like it solved your problem

Comment: Yes, I liked it, and I think it will help me. Thanks dear.